# 4k upscaled Blu-Ray vs 4k upscaling on a TV

Tags: 4k, bluray, 1080p

I was recently looking to purchase Game Of Thrones Season 1 on 4k Blu-Ray however after doing some research it seems that the first season was actually all shot in 1080p so the 4k blu ray discs are is just upscaled versions of the original content.

I was wondering if letting a TV upscale 1080p content to 4K would be any lesser quality than buying the 4k Blu-Ray discs of the upscaled 1080p content.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the methods of upscaling in both cases, but your TV upscales "on the fly" for each moment, which is meant to be fast while compromising on quality. One would imagine a studio releasing a 4k version took their time processing and rendering that 4k upscale to their liking and only then release it.

Comment: Agree with the above. I would not put much into upscaling, whether it is done in studio or in a TV. Sometimes it can harm, for example Back to the Future, Part 1 was oversharpened to my taste when released on BD, I prefer a softer DVD version with less aliasing.